# WCF service with Windows Authentication moved to Azure

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, azure, windows-authentication

I have a WCF service using wsHttpBinding and Windows Authentication hosted in an intranet environment.
Currently I am trying to host that service into Azure VM. Service is not able to authenticate as it is outside local domain.
Please let me know the steps or rather the configuration, I would need for achieving Windows Authentication. IIS configuration WCF web.config configuration etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wealth of information at http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/active-directory/

If you want to using your domain login's.  There are a few approaches to doing this depending on your requirements and this documentation is very good in guiding you to the right solution.